# How to make a full dynamic insert query?

Tags: php, dynamic, insert

I have tried this so far...

```
class Test {

public $table = 'users'
public $fields = ('id', 'username', 'password');
public $id = "";
public $username = "yousufiqbal";
public $password = "123456";

public function fields_to_string(){
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        // some stuff here
    }
}

public function properties_to_string(){
    // some stuff here
}

public function insert(){
    global $dbh;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->table} ($this->fields_to_string()) VALUES ($this->properties_to_string());";
    $dbh->exec($sql);
}
```

}

Comment: maybe I am a little lazy but as a newbie its upto my limits :)

Comment: what is the error are you getting ?

Comment: What is the error you get? Or don't you get an error at all?

Comment: Did I say I'm getting any error ? Not at all

Comment: ``// some stuff here`` is your area to answer.

Comment: Should be, missing a semi-colon on line 3

Comment: Down votes for a tried application isn't a stackoverflow monopoly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
class Test {

    public $table;
    public $fields;
    public $values;

    public function __construct($fields, $values, $table){
        $this->fields = $fields;
        $this->values = $values;
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function fields_to_string(){
        return "`".implode("`, `", $this->fields)."`";
    }

    public function properties_to_string(){
        return "'".implode("', '", $this->values)."'";
    }


    public function insert(){
        global $dbh;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$this->table}` (".$this->fields_to_string().") VALUES (".$this->properties_to_string().");";
        $dbh->exec($sql);
        echo $sql; // for test purposes
    }
}

$fields = array('username', 'password');
$values = array('Mihai', 'stackoverflow');

$test = new Test($fields, $values, 'users');
$test->insert();

// INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('Mihai', 'stackoverflow');
```

Comment: Glad you understood. best regards,

Comment: I didn't down-voted you. On contrary, I liked your question and got +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to have the field values as a array to. This example should get you going:

```
class Test
{    
  public $table = 'users';
  public $fields = array( 'id', 'username', 'password' );
  public $values = array( "", "yousufiqbal", "123456" );

  public function insert()
  {
    global $dbh;
    $fields = '`' . implode( '`,`', $this->fields ) . '`';
    $values = implode( ',', $this->values );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->table` ( $fields ) VALUES ( $values )";
    $dbh->exec( $sql );
  }    
}
```

Your next step would be to implement parameter binding, to prevent SQL injection!

Comment: but my application is a string from property as I fetch using ``PDO::FETCH_INTO`` for my class.

Comment: Down votes for a tried application isn't a stackoverflow monopoly.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: what is the reason for a -1 ? I want to know

Comment: I did not down voted you, I tried to help. Now I will down vote, as you are not being very constructive.

Comment: I didn't say it was you I said what was wrong for me to get -1. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Test {
     public $fields = array('id', 'username', 'password');
     public $properties = array('id' => "", 'username' => "yousufiqbal",'password' =>"123456");
     public function fields_to_string(){        
       $fields_str = implode(',', $this->fields);  
       return $fields_str;
    }

   public function properties_to_string(){
      $properties_str = implode(',', "'".$this->properties."'"); 
      return $properties_str;
    }

   public function insert(){
    global $dbh;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$this->table}` ($this->fields_to_string()) VALUES ($this->properties_to_string());";
    $dbh->exec($sql);
    }
   }
```

Comment: any1 can downvote, need not necessarily be one of the persons who answered, mostly wouldnt be, coz we jus spent some time to answer right ;)

Answer (score -1):

// some stuff here

```
return implode( ',', $this->fields );
```

For the values:

```
return "'" . implode( "','", $this->values ) . "'";
```

Comment: OK but What about ``properties_to_string()`` ?

Comment: It's pretty much the same, what you are probably missing is that there needs to be quotes around the values. See my updated answer.